# How to pass and access environment variables in a text file

Tags: linux, docker

I want to pass environment variables to a text file.

**Use Case:**

I am building a docker image from a Dockerfile and running a java command that makes use of a text file. That text file contains some keywords that I want to pass using environment variables.

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8u151-jdk-alpine3.7

WORKDIR /sink

COPY kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar /sink

COPY cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties /sink

CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -jar kafka-connect-cli-1.0.6-all.jar create cassandra-sink-casb < cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties"]
```

`cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties` is the text file.

**Cassandra-sink-distributed-orders.properties:**

```
name=cassandra-sink-casb
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=topic1
connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM topic1;
connect.cassandra.port=9042
connect.cassandra.key.space=casb
connect.cassandra.contact.points=cassandra
connect.cassandra.username=cassandra
connect.cassandra.password=cassandra
```

In this text file I want to pass `connect.cassandra.username`, `connect.cassandra.password` and `connect.cassandra.key.space` using environment variables.

**This is my docker-compose file:**

```
cassandra-sink:
    container_name: cassandra-sink
    image: casb-cassandra-sink:0.1
    #build:
    #  context: ./cassandra-sink
    #  dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy
    depends_on:
      kafka-connect:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - kafka
      - kafka-connect
      - cassandra
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CONNECT_REST=http://kafka-connect:8083
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) of your text file. You might decide to use some *existing* format such as [JSON](http://json.org/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/) etc... or to invent your own one. In the later case, you should *document* your file format, perhaps using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation. You also would document the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) related to that format (at least in English).

Once you have defined your file format, you need to parse it. There are standard [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) techniques, notably [recursive descent parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) (If you use existing format such as JSON, you'll find many existing libraries handling it).

> I want to pass environment variables to a text file.

Stricto sensu, that does not make any sense. A text file is just a sequence of bytes parsed as some text. You can pass environment variables to *programs* (not to files).

Maybe you could write some [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) using [here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to generate that text file in your script (or feed it to your program on its *stdin*), and run that shell script in your `CMD`  line of your `Dockerfile`.

Maybe your parser might have conventions to handle some notation as meaning to get some environment variable. You'll use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) (or whatever equivalent in your programming language) for that.

You need to become familiar with basic parsing concepts and technologies. So read a good "compiler book", such as the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

You might also consider embedding an interpreter inside your program (look into [scripting languages for Java](https://java-source.net/open-source/scripting-languages)).

Answer (score 2):

You can put environment variables in your properties file, but linux will not automatically recognise them as environment variables and therefore will not resolve them.

```
root@ubuntu:/home# cat a.properties
abc=$abc
xyz=$xyz
```

In order to do this you will have to parse the values.

Just do an export if env variable not already defined

```
root@ubuntu:/home# export abc=1234
root@ubuntu:/home# export xyz=5678
```

Now use the following command to replace the env variables in your properties file and save it as another properties file with env variables resolved.

```
root@ubuntu:/home# envsubst < a.properties > b.properties
```

You can see your results in b.properties file:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# cat b.properties
abc=1234
xyz=5678
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ".env" file for the above properties file and pass it in your docker compose file as follow:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - properties.env
```

Comment: How would I use them in the properties file?

Comment: @EL323 Just to be clear you want to get the values in your properties file from env variables or just defining the values and using it inside container as env variable

Comment: I want to get the values in properties file from env variables

Comment: @EL323 In order to do this you will have to parse the values and resolve any environment variables you find.